# Hide after X characters in php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site, and I want to set up a paywall for certain content.
I would like to show some intro of each such article for Google index and users as well, but rest of it would be hidden for guests and available for logged in (in my case paid users).

I successfully implemented `is_user_logged_in()` PHP statement from Wordpress, but I am not finding PHP code anywhere online about hiding everything after n-characters, or words.

My intended workflow is:

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    the_content();
} else {
    echo 'show only 200 characters or words of the content code should be here';
}
?>
```

Comment: there's a function called [`substr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) in php. or you could google `cut off string php`

Comment: _“but I am not finding PHP code anywhere online”_ - a very basic Google query such as [php cut text after x characters](https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20cut%20text%20after%20x%20characters) would/could/should have given you plenty to start with already.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WordPress default function [wp_trim_words](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_trim_words/).

```
<?php
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        the_content();
    } else {
        $content = get_the_content(); // $content is whatever your content field.
        echo wp_trim_words( $content, 200, ' ' );
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
the_content();
} else {
$content = get_the_content();
//If your template has some other way of getting the post content then use that variable.
echo substr($content, 0, strpos($content, ' ', 200)); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Code only anwsers are rarely helpful. Can you edit and add some explanation as to **how** and **why** your answer works? Thanks